# Convolution between Matrix and Vector

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing, telecommunication

Good day to everyone!

I am writing a matlab program in which I am doing a convolution between each column of Tx and the filter h (i want filter column by column : first column with the filter h, and second column with the filter h,.... and so on)

```
Tx = complex(randn(165,12), randn(165,12));
h=[0.1 -0.05  0.2  -0.5  0.3 0.02];
```

- how can i proceed to filter the whole Tx matrix with the filter h ?

my Matlab code:

```
Tx = complex(randn(165,12), randn(165,12));    
h=[0.1 -0.05  0.2  -0.5  0.3 0.02];
[r c]=size(Tx);

for i=1:c
   Rx=conv(h,Tx(:,i).');
end
```

- i want to conserve the whole resultant Rx matrix ?

Comment: Have you looked at `conv2`?

Comment: @Dan : Thank you and can you give an example with conv2, and how she work ?

Comment: she work exactly like `conv`... try `conv2(h', Tx)` for example. Just read the docs and play around.

Comment: You typically put the matrix as first parameter and the filter as second. It is important if you use 'same' and for internal matlab optimizations. Moreover it is much faster to transpose the small filter, rather then transposing the matrix (which is huge).

Answer (score 0):

Use conv2() with parameter 'same' to preserve the original size or without to get the full convolution.

Example:

```
conv2(ones(5),[1,2.5,-0.7],'same')
conv2(ones(5),[1,2.5,-0.7]','same')
```

The first convolvs each row with the filter and the second convolves each column.

You can use

```
 Rx =conv2(Tx,h','same');
```

Comment: i modified my code and it becomes :  x=conv2(Tx.',h); is that mean i'm trying to filter each column of Tx seperately and finaly i conserve  the whole matrix Rx ?

Comment: Yes. But it is faster to transpose the small filter, rather then transposing the matrix (which is huge). Moreover, if you don't use 'same' than Rx will be larger than Tx